# Objective C Runtime to access screen dimensions

Tags: c++, objective-c, osx-mavericks, objective-c-runtime

I am working on a project where using Cocoa and Objective C is not desired.

I stumbled across the Objective C runtime library the other day and have been trying to use it to access the dimensions of the screen.

This is the code I have currently:

```
auto screen = objc_msgSend(objc_lookUpClass("NSScreen"),sel_getUid("mainScreen")); //Returns an NSScreen*
auto frame = objc_msgSend(screen, sel_getUid("frame")); // should return an NSRect but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and the program quits
```

Using Cocoa isn't an option and Carbon isn't really supported anymore.
I'm hoping that someone is familiar with the Objc Runtime and is able to solve this problem.

Comment: While I can't help you with your problem, I'd be curious as to why one would want to avoid Cocoa. Could you disclose this information?

Comment: @awesomeyi I am fully aware that they aren't the same. The objc runtime api allows you to use the cocoa library without using objective C code.

Comment: @JiaYow I am trying to make a lightweight, cross platform  windowing system for Windows, Mac and Linux. To make it cross platform, I am making this library in C++. I can't make it cross platform without being strictly C++. Objective-C++ won't compile cross platform.

Comment: @ChaseWalden You are wasting your time;  the OS X specific code might as well be in Objective-C with whatever thin layer of C based code on top.  This is how most of the cross platform GUI libraries work as it is.   Using the ObjC runtime via the functional API doesn't mean you are avoiding ObjC, it just means you are using Objective-C the hard way.

Comment: "Objective C is not desired." ... "I stumbled across the Objective C runtime library". Wait, what?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: Objective C as in the language. I still need to be able to access the Cocoa Library in order to properly interface with the computer. I just am unable to compile Objective C code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid Objective-C in getting this information, you'd need to dive into low level Quartz (and good luck with that!).

I think the commands that would help you would be:

[`CGGetActiveDisplayList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGGetActiveDisplayList)
and
[`CGDisplayScreenSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayScreenSize)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about Quartz.

Comment: Quartz isn't really going to help entirely.  You still have to setup the application context, and still need to interface with various system services, all of which is largely available only via the Objective-C APIs in the Foundation and/or AppKit frameworks.

Answer (score 10):

```
auto screen = objc_msgSend(objc_lookUpClass("NSScreen"),sel_getUid("mainScreen")); //Returns an NSScreen*
auto frame = objc_msgSend(screen, sel_getUid("frame")); // BAD_ACCESS
```

The specific reason for the crash is because you need to use one of the variants of objc_msgSend().  Specifically, the one that can return large structures that otherwise don't fit on the stack.

> Using Cocoa isn't an option

Using Cocoa via `objc_msgSend()` is still using Cocoa!

The above code is no more portable to any other platform than simply writing everything as Objective-C.   You still can't use `NSScreen` on Linux or Windows and, thus, there is no point in compiling said lines of code on either platform.

You are far better off taking the same approach as other cross-platform libraries.

• create an API that is your generic cross platform UI API

• under that API, implement as much as you can in portable code

• create a low level bridging API that provides the interface between your portable code and the system

• for each platform implement that bridging API specific to the platform technology desired

This would allow you to use Objective-C directly on OS X while still maintaining a cross-platform API on top.